# Streamlabs custom CSS twitch chat - alternating colors of message and username

Tags: css, css-selectors, twitch

Hope you are all doing fine!
Does anyone knows how to customize Twitch chat box? It's with CSS but some code doesn't look to work
I want to my chat to intercalate between 2 colors, and when I'm doing some work in web pages I use the code :

```
:nth-child()
```

but it doesn't work with in the chat box
the whole css code is:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700);

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000;
    background: {background_color};
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: {font_size};
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: {text_color};
}

#log>div {
    animation: fadeInRight .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
}

.colon {
    display: none;
}

#log {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#log>div {
    display: table-row;
}

#log>div.deleted {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#log .emote {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
}

#log .emote img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
}

#log .message,#log .meta {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
}

#log .meta {
    width: 35%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#log .message {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 65%;
}

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -0.1em;
}

.name {
    margin-left: 0.2em;
}
```

and until now my experiences was:

```
.name {
margin-left: 0.2em;
color:#f578e4;
}
.name:nth-child(2n) {
margin-left: 0.2em;
color:#75fbde;
}
```

turns the message and the username in the #75fbde color

```
#username {
  color:#75fbde;
}
:nth-child(2n) {
      color: #f578e4;
}
```

Create the username class in the html, it makes the username color #75fbde and the message chat color #f578e4
to avoid the color #f578e4 being 2n child of every element, i put as

```
#username {
  color:#75fbde;
}
#username:nth-child(2n) {
      color: #f578e4;
}
```

but it didn't "Obey" the nth code, the username and the message becames #75fbde

so
do you have any idea how to work with twitch chatbox? I'm using streamlabs to code.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this exact thing (but for the whole username including badges, the .meta, not just the name, .name, like you are doing)
And found the solution on [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/ypz65s/css_custom_trying_to_figure_out_some_stuff_and/).

So, basically the html is like this:

```
<div data-from="{from}" data-id="{messageId}">
  <span class="meta" style="color: {color}">
    <span class="badges"></span>
    <span class="name">{from}</span>
  </span>

  <span class="message">
    {message}
  </span>
 </div>
```

As you can see, we don't have siblings for the elements inside, be it the meta, the badges, the name or the message.
All of them are a single member inside the div. The *div* has siblings.

So, with that in mind, to affect one of each two names you would use

```
div:nth-of-type(even) .meta .name {}
```

With me, I wanted to affect just the .meta, so I did not add the.name at the end. So I can assure you it works properly.
And if you wanted to affect the message you would use .message instead of ".meta .name".